# dynamic allocate buffer (string of char) size =i; using malloc

Tags: c++, c

```
scanf ("%d", &i);
```

are these code are the same //dynamic allocate buffer (string of char) size =i;

```
char *buffer = malloc (sizeof((*buffer)*(i+1)));

free(buffer);

char * buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc (i+1);
free(buffer);
```

if yes which is more safe (better)?

Comment: Remember that `sizeof(char)` is *guaranteed* to be one. And don't cast the result of a function returning `void *` (like `malloc`).

Comment: buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));

Comment: `sizeof((*buffer)*(i+1))` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, your parentheses aren't properly arranged.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is:

```
char *buffer = malloc(i + 1);
```

There is no need to cast the return value from `malloc` and `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1 that's standard. So rather than using

`char *buffer = malloc (sizeof((*buffer)*(i+1)));`

you can write this without `sizeof(*buffer)` as:

`char *buffer = malloc(i + 1);`